# Start states in Lex / Flex

Tags: parsing, bison, lex, lexical-analysis, flex-lexer

I'm using Flex and Bison for a parser generator, but having problems with the start states in my scanner.

I'm using exclusive rules to deal with commenting, but this grammar doesn't seem to match quoted tokens:

```
%x COMMENT

//                    { BEGIN(COMMENT); }
<COMMENT>[^\n]        ;
<COMMENT>\n           { BEGIN(INITIAL); }

"=="                  { return EQUALEQUAL; }

.                     ;
```

In this simple example the line:

```
// a == b
```

isn't matched entirely as a comment, unless I include this rule:

```
<COMMENT>"=="             ;
```

How do I get round this without having to add all these tokens into my exclusive rules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Matching C-style comments in Lex/Flex or whatever is well documented:

[in the documentation](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/How-can-I-match-C_002dstyle-comments_003f.html), as well as various variations around the Internet.

Here is a variation on that found in the Flex documentation:

```
   <INITIAL>{
     "//"              BEGIN(IN_COMMENT);
     }
     <IN_COMMENT>{
     \n      BEGIN(INITIAL);
     [^\n]+    // eat comment
     "/"       // eat the lone /
     }
```

Comment: I'd rather not have to use inclusive states if it can be avoided as I have a lot of rules. The problem is this 'eat comment' rule doesn't seem to match tokens with more than one character (such as ==).

Comment: Then I think you might be doing something wrong. You need to create a 'sub parser' for comments, which does not match your normal tokens.

Comment: Say, you want to store the line of each input, then will this give you incorrect line numbers?

Comment: @DonCode iirc yylineno gives the right line regardless of BEGIN "blocks" which you can pass to Bison or whatever

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a "+" after the [^n] rule.  I don't know why the exclusive state is still picking up '==' even in an exclusive state, but apparently it is.  Flex will normally match the rule that matches the most text, and adding the "+" will at least make the two rules tie in length.  Putting the COMMENT rule first will cause it to be used in case of a tie.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is:

> The problem is this 'eat comment'
>   rule doesn't seem to match tokens with
>   more than one character

so add a * to match zero or more non-newlines. You want Zero otherwise a empty comment will not match.

```
%x COMMENT

//                    { BEGIN(COMMENT); }
<COMMENT>[^\n]*        ;
<COMMENT>\n           { BEGIN(INITIAL); }

"=="                  { return EQUALEQUAL; }

.                     ;
```

Comment: An empty comment won't trigger a match for that rule either, nor does it need to.

Comment: True, true, the line below that catches it. so you are safe to change the * to a +