# Input buffer overflow in scanner for long comments

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex

I have defined a LEX scanner with the following rule for scanning (nested) comments:

```
"(*" {
    int linenoStart, level, ch;

    linenoStart = yylineno;
    level = 1;
    do {
        ch = input();
        switch (ch) {
            case '(':
                ch = input();
                if (ch == '*') {
                    level++;
                } else {
                    unput(ch);
                }
                break;
            case '*':
                ch = input();
                if (ch == ')') {
                    level--;
                } else {
                    unput(ch);
                }
                break;
            case '\n':
                yylineno++;
                break;
        }
    } while ((level > 0) && (ch > 0));
    assert((ch >= 0) || (ch == EOF));
    
    if (level > 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: unterminated comment starting at line %d", linenoStart);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

When compiled with FLEX 2.6.4 I get the following error message when I run the scanner on an input file containing a comment with more than 16382 characters:

```
input buffer overflow, can't enlarge buffer because scanner uses REJECT
```

Why is that and how can the problem be resolved?

Comment: It means the input buffer overflowed and cannot be enlarged because you are using REJECT. Solution: don’t  use REJECT.

Comment: @user207421 To my understanding the comment is skipped by reading until its end and no character is stored so what buffer is overflowing? And I see no call to REJECT.

Comment: The *input* buffer. It’s right there in the error message. It’s a long time since I used *flex,* although I contributed code to it, but isn’t there an option about REJECT?

Comment: My understanding of the code is that it's not reading a token into a buffer, it simply skips characters and therefor I don't understand the error message.

Comment: Sigh. The *input* buffer. The *source* of the data. Nothing to do with ‘into a buffer’. Is this really so hard to understand?

Comment: OK, so when a token is matched "only" sixteen thousand something characters are available in the input. In that case, is there a way to discard what's in the buffer and instruct FLEX to read then next 16K characters (or until end of file) into the buffer?

Comment: This answers your question: [Start states in Lex / Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130597/start-states-in-lex-flex).  There are probably several duplicates, but using start-states is common to all of those.

Comment: @ThomasDickey The question you linked to doesn't involve my "naive" approach and why it doesn't work. I have answered my own question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a pattern is matched, in this case `(*`, only `YY_BUF_SIZE` = 16384 characters can be retrieved with the function `input` which reads from a buffer of this size. This limits the size of a comment to `YY_BUF_SIZE` characters. To enable comments of any length we can instead use patterns with a context, like this:

```
"(*" {
    BEGIN(comment);
    commentNestingLevel = 1;
    commentStartLine = yylineno;
}

<comment>[^*(\n]+

<comment>\n {
    yylineno++;
}

<comment>"*"+/[^)]

<comment>"("+/[^*]

<comment>"(*" commentNestingLevel++;

<comment>"*)" {
    commentNestingLevel--;
    if (commentNestingLevel == 0) {
        BEGIN(INITIAL);
    }
}

<comment><<EOF>> {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: unterminated comment starting at line %d", commentStartLine);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: I used to know the *flex* skeleton really well and I'm curious to know why this works. It seems to me that the fundamental problem with the input buffer remains. Or maybe it is that REJECT doesn't occur in the COMMENT state?

Comment: @user207421 Can it be that in the solution above all parts of a comment are matched with patterns so there is no read-ahead buffer involved? The manual only says that "input() reads the next character from the input stream" and gives an example of how to skip C-style comments (which will have the length limitation)
https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html

Comment: I think it is because of handling the line break separately, so that it never has to buffer more than one line.

Comment: @user207421 Indeed, it works as long as each token (each scanned part of the comment) is no longer than YY_BUF_SIZE. I just tried an input file with a single-line comment containing 20000 characters collectively matching the second rule above and then I got the overflow error. A line of this length is not very likely to occur in a real-world scenario though.